# Select Multiple Values SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have a table where the data are as follow

```
ID Classroom Person
1   1         Alfred
2   1         Maria
3   2         Maria
4   2         Zoe
5   2         Alfred
6   3         Nick
7   3         Paul
8   3         Mike
9   3         Alfred
10  4         Zoe
11  4         Maria
```

I want to select and return only the Classroom that has as Person only 'Alfred' and 'Maria' 
Following statement :

```
Select * from table_name where (Person='maria') and (Person=Alfred')
```

doesn't seem to work.

You c[an see a SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/970f3a),

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: So are you trying to get the classroom numbers where both "Alfred" and "Maria" rows exist for that classroom?

Comment: Of course it doesn't work. There is no way a Person will be both 'Alfred' and 'Maria' on the same time. You want it be either 'Alfred' **OR** 'Maria'.

Comment: @DanielA.White he tried to write a query. That's not a very constructive comment here.

Comment: I am trying to select with multple where values (as I wrote in the OP) and with the IN selector but doesn't seem to work. Maybe I'll have to mix in the GROUP BY but it is out of my knowledge, any reference or link would be valuable.

Comment: This is a legitimate (although very basic) question, wonder why the downvote?

Comment: @user3677132 Could you include the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select classroom
from table t
group by classroom
having count(*) = 2 and
       sum(person in ('maria', 'Alfred')) = 2;
```

This assumes that one person cannot be in a classroom multiple times.

This checks that there are two names in the classroom and they are for the two names of interest.  If you can have duplicates, you would want:

```
having count(distinct name) = 2 and
       count(distinct case when person in ('maria', 'Alfred') then person end) = 2;
```

Comment: After a fast test it seems to be working. Thanks a lot Gordon.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. `Group by and having` with `Count` should work.

```
SELECT Classroom
FROM   tablename
WHERE  Person IN( 'maria', 'Alfred' )
GROUP  BY classroom
HAVING Count(Person) = 2
```

Comment: Not quite right . . . The OP appears to want *only* those two names in the classroom.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Sorry i didn't get you. Even my query is doing the same thing.

Comment: . . Your query would pick up classroom = 2, because that has both the names, even though it also has Zoe.

Comment: . . I fixed your SQL Fiddle to have the data in the OP to demonstrate the issue:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/754405.  But in simple terms, the `where` is executed before the `having`, so other names are never considered in the `having`.  Your query is a correct answer to a very similar question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Yea sir you are right. Thanks for making me understand